# How to "Quit and Save" in Firefox 50?

Tags: firefox, configuration

I understand that in earlier Firefox versions (I have seen this feature in Firefox 3 and 4, I don't know when it was removed, or hidden) there was an option in the dialog which asks you if you are sure you want to close the browser which would allow you to `Quit & Save`.

This option would do almost the same thing as force quitting the browser currently does when it crashes or is unresponsive. Is there such an option in Firefox 50? I am running Ubuntu GNOME 16.10 with GNOME 3.22.

I would like there to be an easy way of me accessing this option, however I won't want to use it too often due to security reasons so I don't want it to become the default.

Comment: It always saves the current state on quit now. You can get it back with `History -> Restore Previous Session`. If you have "security reasons" then you need to be in Private Browsing, or manually delete your history.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the address line, type : `about:config`

Type  `browser.showQuitWarning` In the filter field

Double click on the option to switch from `false` to `true` , you will find the `Quit & Save` option again.