# How to prevent Firefox ever saving state on forced quit?

Tags: firefox, security, configuration

When Firefox is forced to quit, such as when it crashes, it will save its current state (e.g.: currently open pages, cookies, etc...). And although I see the convenience in this, from a security perspective it isn't so great...

So I was wondering if there is any way of disabling this feature? I am running Ubuntu GNOME 16.10 with GNOME 3.22 and Firefox 50. Preferably without causing [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/858738/how-to-quit-and-save-in-firefox-50) feature not to work if I choose it in a rare case. Although if the only way to fully disable it is to not allow that option to work either, then so be it.

Comment: There is a setting for that in `about:config`: `browser.sessionstore.resume_from_crash`. Set it to false to disable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type `about:config` in the address line

In the filter field type : `browser.sessionstore.resume_from_crash`

Set the value `false`

Edit your settings , under " When firefox start" set it to "show my home page" or "set a blank page" , do not set " show my windows and tabs from last time "

From The privacy , under History set "Never remember History"